# Google + OAuth and/or DotNetOpenAuth to get a contact list - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I'm probably missing something incredibly obvious here, so that's why I'm asking my question...in the hope that someone can see what I'm missing.  I just learned about OAuth for the first time last week, and I'm trying to use it (in this case) to extract a contact list from someone once they've logged in and authorized it.

Here's what I tried first, using the Google .NET library:

```
        Sub InviteGmailContactsOld()

    Call google_api.GetClientCredentials(Vars.Server_name)
    Dim Input_URL As String = google_api.Token_Request_URL & "?scope=" & OverrideEncode("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/") & "&oauth_callback=" & OverrideEncode(Vars.Site_Root & "my-profile/manage-connections/invite-connections/google/")
    Dim Input_URI As New Uri(Input_URL)
    Dim Authenticator As OAuth3LeggedAuthenticator = New OAuth3LeggedAuthenticator("Politistream API", google_api.Client_ID, google_api.Client_Secret, String.Empty, String.Empty)
    Dim Auth_Request As WebRequest = Authenticator.CreateHttpWebRequest("GET", Input_URI)
    Dim Final_Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(Input_URI)
    Dim Auth_Headers As String = Auth_Request.Headers.ToString()
    Final_Request.Headers.Add(Auth_Headers)
    Final_Request.Method = "GET"
    Response.Write(Final_Request.Headers.ToString() & " <br />" & Final_Request.RequestUri.ToString & "<br />")
    Dim Auth_Response As String = Common.WebRequestToStringResponse(Final_Request)

End Sub
```

Tried this in several variations, and no matter what I did, all I got back from Google was 400 Bad Request.

Then I tried DotNetOpenAuth:

```
        Sub InviteGmailContacts()
    ' GMail uses openID because OAuth doesn't work properly.

    Dim openId As New OpenIdRelyingParty
    Call google_api.GetClientCredentials(Vars.Server_name)
    Dim New_URL As UriBuilder = New UriBuilder(Request.Url.ToString)
    Dim Auth_Request As IAuthenticationRequest = openId.CreateRequest(google_api.OpenID_Login_URL, New_URL.Uri, New_URL.Uri)
    Auth_Request.RedirectToProvider()

End Sub
```

This works, and I was able to get the claimed identifier back.  The problem that I have no is that I have absolutely no idea what the heck I'm supposed to do with it, and I can't find anything anywhere that I can follow along and more or less make my own.

Ideally, what I'm looking for is a code sample that isn't necessarily complete, but is at least coherent enough that I can get where I want to go.  Failing that, an explanation that's dumbed down about three shades from the normal level will suffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing OAuth, which you use in your first code snippet with Google, with OpenID which is in your second snippet.  OpenID gives you, as you noticed, a "claimed identifier" which isn't good for downloading contacts -- it's good for recognizing a user when they come back later.  OpenID is for *authentication* whereas OAuth is for *authorization*.

Since you want to access Google Contacts, that's an *authorization* scenario so you need OAuth.  DotNetOpenAuth does OAuth too, and there's a sample for downloading Contacts in fact (albeit in C#).

[Download dotnetopenauth](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/latest/download) and check out the OAuthConsumerWpf sample.  It has a tab that demonstrates downloading Google Contacts.  It uses code in the DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock sample (the class called `GoogleConsumer`) that will hopefully inspire you on what you can do in your app.

Comment: OAuthConsumerWpf is a good example.  But I don't know why the verification code can not be called back.  User has to manually enter the verification code and click the finish button.  Is it for confirmation purpose?  Is there a way to make the verification code posted back to WPF form automatically.

Comment: I notice that OAuthConsumerWpf is an OAuth2 project.  Does that mean that verification code post back from providers is possible?